# Unsupported channel issue when running pinpoint journey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, aws-pinpoint, journey

I am trying to run amazon connect outbound campaign through pinpoint, In pinpoint project i have uploaded segment(contact info) and created journey that specify which amazon connect instance and which campaign to run. but when journey executed the campaign is not running and in journey metrics it is showing unsupported channel issue.

[here is the screen shot of journey metrics after its execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW5PO.png)

to solve this i have already enable SMS and Voice channel in my pinpoint project and also give IAM role to run connect campaign. And in Connect i have setup outbound campaign along with the all required things like queues, routing profile, contact flow.